# Selecting the average of the top percent of duration, grouped by minute

Tags: sql-server, time

I am attempting to find the average of (the top 5% of duration/ per minute).

I wrote this query:

```
select AVG(Q.duration) Avg5Perc, Q.time FROM
(

          select top 5 PERCENT duration, time from table (nolock)
          WHERE time between '2015-06-5 13:00' and '2015-06-5 13:59.99'
) Q
group by datepart(minute, Q.time), Q.table
ORDER BY Q.table desc;
```

Basically, in the sub-select I am acquiring the top 5 percent of values, and in the outer select I am averaging them. However, when I run the query, I do not actually have it grouped by minute.

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by top 5%?  That subquery has no ORDER BY clause which means the "top 5 percent" could be any 5% of the rows in the table.

Answer (score 2):

Start by working out the duration per minute:

```
select sum(duration) as dpm,  datediff(minute, '2015-06-5 13:00', time) as mins_since_start 
from table
where time >= '2015-06-5 13:00' 
and time < '2015-06-5 14:00'
group by datediff(minute, '2015-06-5 13:00', time)
```

Now get the top 5 percent of this.

```
select top (5) percent sum(duration) as dpm,  datediff(minute, '2015-06-5 13:00', time) as mins_since_start
from table
where time >= '2015-06-5 13:00' 
and time < '2015-06-5 14:00'
group by datediff(minute, '2015-06-5 13:00', time)
order by dpm desc
```

Then wrap it up and get the

```
select AVG(Q.dpm) Avg5Perc
FROM
(select top (5) percent sum(duration) as dpm,  datediff(minute, '2015-06-5 13:00', time) as mins_since_start
from table
where time >= '2015-06-5 13:00' 
and time < '2015-06-5 14:00'
group by datediff(minute, '2015-06-5 13:00', time)
order by dpm desc
) Q;
```

This then gives you the average of the top five percent. I prefer to use datediff like this because it means you're not restricted to a single hour.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having some difficulty understanding your goals, but below is code based on my interpretation. This is in the context of your sql-server tag. This is completely self-contained, with sample data generation provided.

```
CREATE TABLE DataTable
(
    Duration int DEFAULT ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 180,
    [Time] datetime2(0) DEFAULT DATEADD(minute, (ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % (180)), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
);
GO

INSERT INTO DataTable DEFAULT VALUES;
GO 5000

;WITH
TransformData(Duration, Minute)
AS
(
    SELECT Duration, LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, [Time], 108), 5) FROM DataTable
),
AverageData(DurationAverage, Minute)
AS
(
    SELECT AVG(Duration) as DurationAverage, Minute
    FROM TransformData
    GROUP BY Minute
),
NTileData(NT, DurationAverage, Minute)
AS
(
    SELECT NTILE(20) OVER (ORDER BY DurationAverage), DurationAverage, Minute
    FROM AverageData
)
SELECT DurationAverage, Minute
FROM NTileData
WHERE NT = 20
ORDER BY NT DESC, DurationAverage DESC;
GO
```

Here is the output:

```
DurationAverage Minute
--------------- ------
115             21:47
113             23:37
112             21:49
111             23:55
109             00:06
109             23:26
109             22:01
108             22:47
107             21:43
```